# How do I pass a value from a controller to a JSP page in Spring?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, spring-boot

I'm trying to pass data from a Controller to a JSP page but I'm running into a few issues. There's a method in the Controller that will query a database of house price information based on a latitude and longitude value provided by a user. A debug shows that the database is queried correctly as it prints a `houseprice` value and the number of `houses` in the results to Eclipe's console but I can't get the JSP page to load and therefore get it to print to the JSP page.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/parseHousePrice", method={RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
 public @ResponseBody String parseHousePrice(@RequestBody HousePrice housePriceObject, 
                                             @RequestParam("latitude") double latitude,
                                             @RequestParam("longitude") double longitude, 
                                             Model model) {

  double housePriceAverage = parseHousePrice.ParseHousePrice(latitude, longitude);

  // This passes the lat & long into a method that will query the database
  List<Double> housePriceList = parseHousePrice.getList();
  // This will return the number of houses that were queried
  int housePriceListSize = housePriceList.size();

  // This print statement successfully prints the results fromt he query
  System.out.println("The average house price for this area is: " + housePriceAverage + " based on " + housePriceListSize + " property prices in this area");

  model.addAttribute("houseprice", housePriceAverage);
  model.addAttribute("housepricelistsize", housePriceListSize);

  // JSP Page I'm trying to pass the information above to
  return "houseprice"; 
}
```

The data is sent via an AJAX request in a Javascript function **on one JSP** and I'm trying to open a **new JSP page** with the information from the controller

```
   function parseHousePrice(){

       // Calculates users latitude and longitude
       $('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
       var Lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
       console.log(Lat);

       $('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
       var Long = marker.getPosition().lng();
       console.log(Long);

       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/parseHousePrice",
                data: { latitude: Lat, 
                        longitude: Long,  
                      }, 
                datatype: 'json'
       });

    }
```

And I call it from a link in a navbar like so:

```
 <li><a href= "javascript:parseHousePrice();" >House Price</a></li>
```

In the JSP page I've tried a few ways to collect the information calculated above and display it. One way was use thymleaf but this won't print

```
 <h4>Average House Price <text th:text="${houseprice}" /> </h4>
 <h4>Number of Houses the average is caluclated by: <text th:text="${housepricelistsize}" /> </h4>
```

Another way was to drop the thymeleaf and call it like this:

```
 <h1>${houseprice} </h1>
 <h1>${housepricelistsize} </h1>
```

However, there is no luck. I can get the information successfully passed into the controller and printed into the console, but passing it from the controller to the JSP page is where I'm having trouble. Any help would be appreciated!

Screenshot of application[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you show what you did on your jqery ajax done() ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, I've included the Ajax query (that passes a latitude and longitude value to the controller) in the question if that's what you meant.

Comment: so once ajax return your data what are you doing? where is you done() function ?

Comment: I don't actually have a `done()` function, I'm not sure what that is. The ajax query just sends the data to the controller and then I'm trying to open a **new page** with the information from the controller. Do you think the fact I don't have a `done()` function is causing this error?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Once you call your controller via ajax call, it will return you json object. Now you have to use this json object to populate your jsp page. Either you are not providing complete info or your code is incomplete. Check jqery ajax page to see what is done() function.

Comment: Apologies if I haven't been clear. I'll try again now and I've included a screenshot of my application. The user will search an address and Google Maps API will convert it into a latitude and longitude value. When the user clicks `House Price` in the navbar, the `parseHousePrice();` function will be called and it will send the latitude and longitude to the controller. The controller then passes the latitude and longitude values into a java method `ParseHousePrices()` and this will return the average house price of the houses in a 1KM radius. The print statement then prints this.

Comment: ParseHousePrices()  will return the average house price of the houses in a 1KM radius as a json format. Now you have to write jquery script to get these value and render your jsp.

Comment: Sorry for the back and forth messaging here I really appreciate your help. Would I write that jquery script in the JSP page I'm trying to pass the data to?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are trying to update your jsp page with house price and size when navbar is clicked. I am trying to answer this based on what I understand.

In your jsp I would put something like,

```
<h1 id ="housepriceID"></h1>
 <h1 id ="housepricesize"> </h1>
```

Now on your jQuery,

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/parseHousePrice",
                data: { latitude: Lat, 
                        longitude: Long,  
                      }, 
                datatype: 'json'
       })
.done(function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {    
    $("#housepriceID").val(data.houseprice);
    $("#housepricesize").val(data.housepricelistsize);

            });
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, the code, `model.addAttribute` should be `model.setAttribute`, because you want to add the data queried from the database to the session, so you have to use `.setAttribute` instead.